# Question about monotonicity

Tags: calculus

Let's say there's a function that is:
increasing in $$(-\infty, 0]$$ and $$(4, +\infty)$$
decreasing in $$(0, 4]$$

Can we say it's increasing in $$(-\infty, 0] \cup (4, +\infty)$$
or it's increasing in $$(-\infty, 0] , (4, +\infty)$$
What about the closure? Can we use <> in defining monotonicity?

Comment: What does $(-\infty,0>$ mean? Is it $(-\infty,0)$ or $(-\infty,0]$. This matters.

Comment: Changed that, @Nameless, you were right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would often be incorrect to say the first option.  A function from a subset of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ is called increasing if for all $x,y\in A$, $x\leq y$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$.  If $f$ is increasing on $A$ and increasing on $B$, that does not imply that $f$ is increasing on $A\cup B$.  For example, if $f(x)=x^3-6x^2$, then $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,0]$ and increasing on $[4,\infty)$, but not increasing on $(-\infty,0]\cup[4,\infty)$ because $f(-1)>f(5)$.

The second option could be ambiguous.  It would be correct to say that $f$ is increasing on each of the two intervals, and if that message could be accurately conveyed by placing a comma between them, that's fine.  But how clear it is may depend on the target audience (after all, you're asking), and it doesn't hurt to state what you mean a little more explicitly when you're not sure.

I don't know what you are asking about the closure of something, or what you are asking about using "<> in defining monotonicity".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's say I need to define the monocity of f(x)=|x|.
It's decreasing in $$(-\infty, 0]$$ and increasing in  $$[0, +\infty]$$?
or
It's decreasing in $$(-\infty, 0)$$ and increasing in  $$(0, +\infty)$$?

Comment: @TomDavies92: All 4 of those statements are correct.

Comment: ok, last question: f(x)=x, the domain is real without 0. Can I say it's increasing in $$(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, +\infty)$$

Comment: @TomDavies92: It is correct to say that; $x<y$ implies $x<y$.